# Swift creates strange values after initialization

Tags: cocoa, swift

I have created a very simple base class with a vector/matrix.

```
class base {
   var matrix: [Float]?
}

class someClass : base {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.matrix = [1.2, 0.9, 1.1, 1.0, 0.8]
    }
}
```

Why is my numbers not exactly 1.20000000, 0.9000000 an so on? Check the console output in the attached screenshot. If I change the matrix to [Double] we are getting even more awkward results.

[image]

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de